# Convert u'\xe0' to '\u00E0' in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

In Python 2.x, how can I convert an unicode string (ex, `u'\xe0'`) to a string (here I need it to be `'\u00E0'`)?

To make it clearer. I do like to have `'\u00E0'`, a string with length of 6. That is, `¥u` is treated as 2 chars instead of one escaped char.

Comment: `\u` is not a recognized escape sequence in Python. Are you indending to create a UTF-16-encoded string or a JSON string?

Comment: If you made a mistake here and want to have (u'\u00E0') instead of ('\u00E0') from u'\xE0' there is nothing you should do as these are the same strings. So please clarify if that was intended and contains no error.

Comment: Do you need `r'\u00E0'` which is same as `'\\u00E0'`?

Comment: In a unicode literal (`u'...'`), the escape codes `\u00e0` and `\xe0` result in the *exact same codepoint*. There is no difference. Python uses the latter form for codepoints in the U+0000-U+00FF range (when outside the printable ASCII range) when using `repr()`, but it is the same codepoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\u` doesn't exist as a string escape sequence in Python 2.

You might mean a JSON-encoded string:

```
>>> s = u'\xe0'
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(s)
'"\\u00e0"'
```

or a UTF-16 (big-endian)-encoded string:

```
>>> s.encode("utf-16-be")
'\x00\xe0'
```

but your original request is not fulfillable.

As an aside, note that `u'\u00e0'` is identical to `u'\xe0'`, but `'\u00e0'` doesn't exist:

```
>>> u'\u00e0'
u'\xe0'
```

Comment: `\u` *is* an escape sequence, see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: @JanneKarila: Right, but only in Unicode objects, not strings. I should be more specific.